# How to replace stock java with downloaded binary?

Tags: linux, debian, java, binary, openjdk

In Debian Stable the latest `openjdk` version available is `17`.

```bash
$ which -a java
/usr/bin/java
/bin/java
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.8 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+7-Debian-1deb12u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+7-Debian-1deb12u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I wanted to test out `21` which will be released soon so I downloaded the binaries directly.

```bash
$ curl https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk21/fd2272bbf8e04c3dbaee13770090416c/35/GPL/openjdk-21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
$ tar -xzf openjdk-21_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
$ cd jdk-21
$ ./bin/java --version
openjdk 21 2023-09-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21+35-2513)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21+35-2513, mixed mode, sharing)
$ which -a java
/usr/bin/java
/bin/java
$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.8 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8+7-Debian-1deb12u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.8+7-Debian-1deb12u1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I would like all my scripts to use the new java binaries without having to manually edit all `java` entries in them. That is, when invoking `java` I would like the new binaries to run. Can I replace stock `java` by simply copy pasting to `/usr/bin/` and `/bin/`? That is, will this work?

```bash
$ mv ./bin/* /usr/bin/
$ mv ./bin/* /bin/
```

Do I also need to copy other folders in `jdk-21` such as `conf` and `lib`? Can replacing stock java cause any side effects?

Comment: Don't. It's always a bad idea to make changes to a installed package by other means than using the corresponding package manager.

Answer (score 1):

Simply modify `PATH` so that `realpath ./bin` comes first.

For example, in `~/.bashrc`, you can use `export PATH="/home/yyhh344/Downloads/java-21/bin:$PATH"`.

You may also need to set `JAVA_HOME` and [other Java environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26640589) depending on your usage.